# In these sentences, are these direct objects and oprds?

Tags: dependency-grammar

I read about `oprd` (object predicative: https://www.thoughtco.com/object-predicative-grammar-1691446) and I was thinking about the following sentences. Am I correctly identifying the `direct object` and the `oprd`:

**Sentence #1**

`He found her interesting`

**direct object**: her

**oprd**: interesting

Spacy classifies it as ccomp instead and no direct object: https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=he%20found%20her%20interesting&model=en_core_web_lg&cpu=1&cph=1

**Sentence #2**

`He made her very happy`

**direct object**: her

**oprd**: very happy

**Sentence #3**

`he painted me green`

**direct object**: me

**oprd**: green

Comment: I've never heard linguists use a contraction "oprd" and I suggest you don't either. I haven't really heard the term "object predicate" either, but if it refers to the adjective phrases, then yes you've identified them correctly.

Comment: Here's some info about this: https://www.thoughtco.com/object-predicative-grammar-1691446

Comment: Added it to the question for reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your analyses are correct. The adjectives *interesting*, *very happy*, and *green* are object predicatives, that is, they are predications over the object each time (not over the subject). The dependency grammar analysis of object predicatives is likely to posit a flat, tertiary branching structure, e.g.

[image]

The flatness of these structures is suggestive of the semantic relationship between the object and the predicative adjective, whereby the adjective serves to assign a property to the object: 'She is interesting', 'She is very happy', and 'I am green'.

There is a qualitative difference across your examples that is noteworthy. In the case of *interesting* and *very happy*, the meaning of the sentence would shift dramatically if they were not present. The sentences *He found her* and *He made her* have drastically different meanings from *He found her interesting* and *He made her very happy*. Concerning your third example, however, the shift in meaning across *He painted me* and *He painted me green* is only slight. This difference across the examples suggests that *interesting* and *very happy* are complements, whereas *green* is an adjunct. The adjunct status of *green* is indicated in the third tree with the arrow head pointing away from *green* towards its governor *painted*.

Finally, the particular tag used to identify an object predicative expression, i.e. oprd, is somewhat arbitrary, that is, it is the abbreviations used by a particular annotation scheme. Other annotation schemes might use some other abbreviation, e.g. objpd, obprd, etc., or they might call it something entirely different, e.g. xcomp.

Comment: great answer, thank you. Also, thanks for pointing out the adjunct bits, hadn't noticed that difference and the inverted arrow symbology